# pointwise function question

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$, $f_n:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions on a set $X$, and suppose that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise on $X$. Prove that $(f_n)_+ \rightarrow f_+$ and $(f_n)_{-} \rightarrow f_{-}$ pointwise on $X$.

Need help to prove this. I am not sure where to start since I did not find anything related in  my notes and not sure which part of text to look at in my book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**. Fix a point $x\in X$. Then either $f(x)$ has a sign, in which case $f_n(x)$ has a sign too for $n$ sufficiently big, or $f(x)=0$. In the latter case, what is the possible behaviour of $f_n(x)$?

Comment: For the latter case, the obvious inequality $(f_n)_+\le \lvert f_n\rvert$ might also come in handy.